Finding All Linear Factors of a Determinant for a Given 3x3 matrix
I am working on finding all the linear factors of the determinant of the following $3\times 3$ matrix:
\begin{vmatrix}
a & a^3 & a^4 \\
b & b^3 & b^4 \\
c & c^3 & c^4
\end{vmatrix}
I have managed to identify six factors out of the expected eight linear factors. The factors I have identified are:

(a - b)
(a - c)
(b - c)
(a)
(b)
(c)

I understand that if any two rows are identical, the determinant becomes zero, which gives me the factors (a - b), (a - c), and (b - c). Similarly, if any variable (a), (b), or (c) is zero, the determinant also becomes zero, leading to the factors (a), (b), and (c).
Given that the determinant is a polynomial of degree 8 in (a), (b), and (c), I am expecting to find a total of 8 linear factors.
And then expand along that column, but the algebra was tough.
My Attempts:

Row and Column Operations:

I tried to perform column operations to simplify the matrix and reduce it to a form where I could easily expand along a column or row. However, the resulting algebra was complex and hard to manage.



Questions:

What are the remaining two linear factors I am missing?
Is there a simpler way to determine all the linear factors of the determinant for this matrix without getting bogged down in complex algebra?

Additional Context:
I understand that the polynomial degree of the determinant is 8, which aligns with having 8 linear factors. My current identified factors only account for 6 of these. I suspect the remaining factors might be related to combinations or repeated terms, but I need help identifying them clearly.
Any insights or simpler methods for finding the missing factors would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your help!

The right idea is indeed to use row and columns operations.
Let $D$ be your determinant. Using the fact that the determinant in linear in each row, you get immediately $D=abc\begin{vmatrix}1 & a^2 & a^3\cr 1 &b^2 & b^3 \cr 1 & c^2 & c^3 \end{vmatrix}$.
Let $D'$ the previous $3\times 3$ determinant.
Performing $C_3\leftarrow C_3-aC_2$, then $C_2\leftarrow C_2-a^2C_1$ yields $D'=\begin{vmatrix}1 & 0 &0\cr  1 & (b+a)(b-a)&b^2(b-a)\cr  1 &(c+a)(c-a) & c^2(c-a)\end{vmatrix}.$ Expanding wrt to the first row and using again linearity wrt to each row yields $D'=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}b+a & b^2 \cr c+a & c^2\end{vmatrix}.$
Performing $L_2\leftarrow L_2-L_1$ in the $2\times 2$ determinant gives $D'=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix}b+a & b^2 \cr c-b & (c-b)(c+b)\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\begin{vmatrix}b+a & b^2 \cr 1 & c+b\end{vmatrix}.$
Finally, $D'=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)(bc+ac+ab)$.
All in all, $D=abc(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)(bc+ac+ab)$.
Note the last factor is quadratic and cannot be expected to be factored into a product of linear factors (if $a,b,c$ are independent indeterminates over $\mathbb{C}$, this factor is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c]$).
